# Display image from Another base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have separate urls for admin backend and frontend.my file structure is like below.
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55I3U.png    in admin folder there is appliction system folders and css images and etc.
frontend url - localhost/abc
backend url - localhost/abc/admin
now i want to display images in frontend from upload folder in admin folder.

how i do it.

```
<?php echo "<img src='" . base_url().$post->image."' width=150px; height=100px;>";?>
```

according to this part of view base url is localhost/abc.

now i want add the backend url insted of frontend base url.

**view**

```
 <?php if($post) { ?> 
    <?php foreach($post as $post){?> 
    <tr> 
    <td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td> 
    <!--<td><?php echo $post->image ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></td>-->
             <td><?php echo "<img src='" . base_url().$post->image."' width=150px; height=100px;>";?></td></td> 
    </tr> 
    <?php } 
    } else {

        ?> 
    <tr><td clospan="4" align="center">No records found to display</td></tr> 


    <?php } ?>
```

**controller**

```
public function index(){  

 $data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_plan(); // calling Post model method getPosts() 
        $this->load->view('user_include/header');
        $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data);
    }
```

**model**

```
function get_plan(){


$this->db->select("floor_plan.id,floor_plan.image"); 
$this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']); 
$this->db->from('floor_plan');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();


}
```

Comment: check this part of your code, <?php foreach($post as $post){?>

Comment: i want to change the base url

Comment: try to get current url for base url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248970/codeigniter-get-current-url-relative-to-base-url

Comment: upload image folder is placed in admin folder. my view ,controller, and model in application folder.now i want to display image in admin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><?php echo "<img src='".base_url().'admin'.$post->image."' width=150px; height=100px;>";?></td>
```