# Redirect to the same page after switching the language in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have language switcher on my website, it works fine. However, it redirects to base URL.

But when I write `redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);` it doesn't redirect correctly. When I change the new language on the home page, I should stay at the same URL and just  make the website change the language.

How do I solve this problem?

Here is my controller:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class LanguageSwitcher extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('url');    
    }

    function switchLang($language = "") {

        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

        redirect(base_url());

    }
}
```

Also, I have tried this, it did not work for me:

```
function switchLang($language = "") {

        if($this->uri->uri_string() == '') {

            $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

            redirect(base_url());
        } else {

            $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

            redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: have u tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651479/8197560 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21264228/8197560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with sessions, but I prefer this approach which makes use of an uri-query: What it does, is adding a `?my-current-url` part to the link where you call the new language.

So, in my **view**, I've a link (button, etc.) which calls the language switcher, adding the current site url as **uri-query** like this:

```
<?php 
  // set pathname from where we came from
     $pn=uri_string();  // the uri class is initialized automatically
?>
<a href="/LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/azerbaijani?<?=$pn?>">Azerbaijani</a>
```

then in your function `switchLang()` you take care of the redirect:

```
function switchLang($language = "") {
    // get pathname from where we came from
    $pn= parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "azerbaijani";
    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

    // redirect to where we came from
       redirect($pn, 'refresh');    
}
```

Comment: it means at the url every time will be `?az` or `?rus` ?

Comment: no, only at the link(button) or whatever you use to click on, there the new language shows. This is obviously based on your quote: "I have language switcher on my website, it works fine" ?$pn will give you the pathname where you came from

Comment: First, it redirects to `LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/russian ` page and in a moment redirects to that page where I have changed the language. Is it normal?

Comment: no, the <a href=""></a> part calls the controller, where you are redirected to the new language page, it should be the same as in your original approach, but instead of redirect(base_url()); now it redirects to the page you came from, but in the new language... BUT WAIT i've set $config['index_page'] = ''; and removed the index part with .htaccess, that could mess up the whole strategy

Comment: should I remove it also?

Comment: I would, as it is much nicer looking, also think about using routes, then you can associate an inmyownlanguage-link to your controller/function, you'll find all about routes in the CI manual

Comment: Last question, if I don't change .htaccess and route, will there be any problems in future?

Comment: it should work well any way. You said earlier: "it redirects to LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/russian page" but there is no page called in that controller, just a redirect, which works well on my sites Anyway, you can debug your php code quite easy with e.g. adding this line `echo $pn;die();` before your `redirect()` and see what is the outcome. Play around to make the link work as you need. hope this helped....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160227/discussion-between-vickel-and-javid-abbasov).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
redirect($url);
```

Comment: best and shortest answer. works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
redirect($uri, 'refresh');
```

where `$uri` is the url of the home page that you want to translate

Comment: Should I define URI before?

Comment: That would be great

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this might help you**

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if ($this->agent->is_referral())
{
    echo $this->agent->referrer();
}
```

Comment: Where should I write this?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/user_agent.html  refer this link for more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Base Site URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
    | WITH a trailing slash:
    |
    |   http://example.com/
    |
    | WARNING: You MUST set this value!
    |
    | If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
    | your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
    | to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
    | The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
    | development and MUST NOT be used in production!
    |
    | If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
    | a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
    |
    */
    $config['base_url'] = 'your domain';
```

Try to change the base_url in your config.php inside application/config directory with your URL address complete.

Comment: I do not need this

Answer (score 0):

What I do in all my projects (maybe not an easy solution for what you're asking for, but realy useful for this and other scenarios) is to use two helpers, I called them **history()** and **back()**.

History saves current url in an array in session:

```
$history[] = current_url();
$ci->session->set_userdata('history', $history);
```

Back($num) receives a number and redirect to that position.
i.e: back(1) is equivalent to "send me to the last visited page".

```
$history = $this->session->userdata('history');
$cant = count($history);
$back = $cant - $num;
redirect($history[$back]);
```

Then in the __construct() of "CI_Controller" (or whatever class you extend your controllers) call `history()` once to log every method.

Also, you can add a third controller, I call it **no_history()**.

no_history() deletes the last saved URL (I use it in methods that I don't want to save, for example, ajax requests). You can also check **$this->input->is_ajax_request()** but it's just an idea.

That's it, now you have a history of visited URLs.
You can change whatever you want, and then **back(1)**.
Also useful for redirect your users to whatever they were doing before login.

Oh! Almost forgot: Remember to limit the size of the array and always delete the oldest url before adding new one. Between five and ten will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**First load under constructor method like as:**

```
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('user_agent');
}
```

**After inserting or updating data then it will work fine.**

```
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```